# After sorting an array, why am I seeing addresses instead of values?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a small problem in my code. I'm trying to count the largest number in the input, and I wanted to try it by using `std::sort()`. Right now I have this code, which prints to the output the address of the largest number rather than the largest number itself:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int arr[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
        int x;  
        cin >> x;
        arr[x]; 
    }
    sort(arr, arr + 3, greater<int>());

    cout << arr[0] << endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I calling `sort` incorrectly?

Comment: change to ` cin >> arr[i];`.

Comment: You should use the right header (`#include <algorithm>`).

Comment: I think you might mean `arr[i] = x;` in the loop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He's using sort correctly, so that wouldn't have helped much.

Comment: @user3420119 And never forget to ask the compiler for warnings using `-Wall`! (`main.cpp:10:14: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]   arr[x];`) [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b24625ad938c70d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `sort` is correct, but your initialization of the array isn't. You're writing

```
for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
    int x;  
    cin>>x;
    arr[x]; 
}
```

That last statement, `arr[x];`, has no effect. What you're interpreting as an address being printed is instead a garbage value that just coincidentally happens to be in the first spot in the array.

I think you meant to write

```
arr[i] = x;
```

Once you do that, everything should start working.

Even better, try writing this:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
    cin >> arr[i];
}
```

Going forward, make sure you crank your compiler's warning level up to maximum. I'm pretty sure that most compilers would detect that your statement had no effect, which would have keyed you into the root cause of the problem.

Hope this helps!